# mongoose push item to array in array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to push element to marked array?

[image]

Comment: see [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), 1) post some sample document in json instead of image, 2) post what you have tried? 3) after try what is the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try

```
let commentId = "",
let replies = ""
Model.update(
  { comment: { $elemMatch: { _id: commentId } } },
  {
    $push: { "comment.$.replies": replies  },
  }
);
```

**[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mRiSR-3jVHl)**